How to repeat a list of names multiple times in EXCEL and repeat that list
I found a solution to take a list:
alpha
bravo
charlie

and repeat that list a number of times:
alpha
alpha
alpha
bravo
bravo
bravo
charlie
charlie
charlie

I am trying to now duplicate that list a number of times - but it is fruitless so far:
alpha
alpha
alpha
bravo
bravo
bravo
charlie
charlie
charlie
alpha
alpha
alpha
bravo
bravo
bravo
charlie
charlie
charlie
alpha
alpha
alpha
bravo
bravo
bravo
charlie
charlie
charlie

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?
I haven't tried anything on my own... i am looking for a solution online... but of the things I've tried (which I can't recall.... maybe INDEX, REPT, and a handful of others) but i'm not getting the results I'm seeking (listed above)

Using the information from the second answer on question Excel - Repeat list items multiple times, I found the following solution :
=TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(1,3),TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(1,3),A1:A3),1)),1, TRUE)

Column A is raw data
Column B is =TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(1,3),A1:A3),1)
Column C is =TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(1,3),TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(1,3),A1:A3),1)),1, TRUE)

I am also trying to find a solution using the INDEX function as the other answers on that post used, but I haven't found one that works yet.

Using Excel 365:
=SORT(
 INDEX($A$1:$A$3,
 MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS($A$1:$A$3)*x*y)-1,
 ROWS($A$1:$A$3))+1))

x -  the number of times you want each value in the original list to repeat consecutively
y - the number of times you want the entire list to duplicate
